# Change IsChecked property on ChangePropertyAction [uwp]

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, ischecked

I need to change the **IsChecked** property of a Radio Button on the click of a simple Button in XAML using **ChangePropertyAction**.
I am able to change every property of the radio button (Content, Visibility etc) through this method except IsChecked and it gives a unnamed error.

```
<Button x:Name="button1">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button1}">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=radio1}" PropertyName="IsChecked" Value="false"/>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

May I know the reason and the solution please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems due to this, checkbox ischecked property is inherit from its base class ToggleButton. And it's value is Nullable(See details from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked)). And that's why it reports exception like the following:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>   name expected [Line: 1 Position: 175]
>      at Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xaml)
>      at Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.TypeConverterHelper.Convert(String value, String destinationTypeFullName)

To solve this problem, try create a converter yourself:

```
 public class NullReaderConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then on your XAML, try the following:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:NullReaderConverter x:Name="myconverter"/>
        <x:Boolean x:Key="falsevalue">false</x:Boolean>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <RelativePanel>
        <CheckBox Content="test1" x:Name="radio1" IsChecked="True"></CheckBox>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="change" RelativePanel.Below="radio1">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button1}">
                    <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=radio1}" PropertyName="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myconverter},Source={StaticResource falsevalue}}"/>
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
    </RelativePanel>

</Grid>
```